# DateTime Conversion Issue [UTC -> Mountain -> UTC]

Tags: c#, datetime, dst

Server response using original UTC:

**TimeSlot: "2009-11-01T06:00:00Z"

TimeSlot: "2009-11-01T06:05:00Z"

TimeSlot: "2009-11-01T06:10:00Z"

TimeSlot: "2009-11-01T06:15:00Z"

TimeSlot: "2009-11-01T06:20:00Z"

TimeSlot: "2009-11-01T06:25:00Z"

TimeSlot: "2009-11-01T06:30:00Z"

TimeSlot: "2009-11-01T06:35:00Z"

TimeSlot: "2009-11-01T06:40:00Z"

TimeSlot: "2009-11-01T06:45:00Z"

TimeSlot: "2009-11-01T06:50:00Z"

TimeSlot: "2009-11-01T06:55:00Z"

TimeSlot: "2009-11-01T07:00:00Z"

TimeSlot: "2009-11-01T07:05:00Z"

TimeSlot: "2009-11-01T07:10:00Z"

TimeSlot: "2009-11-01T07:15:00Z"

TimeSlot: "2009-11-01T07:20:00Z"

TimeSlot: "2009-11-01T07:25:00Z"

TimeSlot: "2009-11-01T07:30:00Z"

TimeSlot: "2009-11-01T07:35:00Z"

TimeSlot: "2009-11-01T07:40:00Z"

TimeSlot: "2009-11-01T07:45:00Z"

TimeSlot: "2009-11-01T07:50:00Z"

TimeSlot: "2009-11-01T07:55:00Z"**
TimeSlot: "2009-11-01T08:00:00Z"
TimeSlot: "2009-11-01T08:05:00Z"
TimeSlot: "2009-11-01T08:10:00Z"
TimeSlot: "2009-11-01T08:15:00Z"
TimeSlot: "2009-11-01T08:20:00Z"
TimeSlot: "2009-11-01T08:25:00Z"
TimeSlot: "2009-11-01T08:30:00Z"
TimeSlot: "2009-11-01T08:35:00Z"
TimeSlot: "2009-11-01T08:40:00Z"
TimeSlot: "2009-11-01T08:45:00Z"
TimeSlot: "2009-11-01T08:50:00Z"
TimeSlot: "2009-11-01T08:55:00Z"
TimeSlot: "2009-11-01T09:00:00Z"

---

After using the code below the DST intervals are moved:

```
DateTime.SpecifyKind(time, DateTimeKind.Utc).ConvertUtcTimeToMountainTime().ConvertMountainTimeToUtcTime()
```

The response

TimeSlot: "2009-11-01T06:00:00Z"
TimeSlot: "2009-11-01T06:05:00Z"
TimeSlot: "2009-11-01T06:10:00Z"
TimeSlot: "2009-11-01T06:15:00Z"
TimeSlot: "2009-11-01T06:20:00Z"
TimeSlot: "2009-11-01T06:25:00Z"
TimeSlot: "2009-11-01T06:30:00Z"
TimeSlot: "2009-11-01T06:35:00Z"
TimeSlot: "2009-11-01T06:40:00Z"
TimeSlot: "2009-11-01T06:45:00Z"
TimeSlot: "2009-11-01T06:50:00Z"
TimeSlot: "2009-11-01T06:55:00Z"
**TimeSlot: "2009-11-01T08:00:00Z"

TimeSlot: "2009-11-01T08:00:00Z"

TimeSlot: "2009-11-01T08:05:00Z"

TimeSlot: "2009-11-01T08:05:00Z"

TimeSlot: "2009-11-01T08:10:00Z"

TimeSlot: "2009-11-01T08:10:00Z"

TimeSlot: "2009-11-01T08:15:00Z"

TimeSlot: "2009-11-01T08:15:00Z"

TimeSlot: "2009-11-01T08:20:00Z"

TimeSlot: "2009-11-01T08:20:00Z"

TimeSlot: "2009-11-01T08:25:00Z"

TimeSlot: "2009-11-01T08:25:00Z"

TimeSlot: "2009-11-01T08:30:00Z"

TimeSlot: "2009-11-01T08:30:00Z"

TimeSlot: "2009-11-01T08:35:00Z"

TimeSlot: "2009-11-01T08:35:00Z"

TimeSlot: "2009-11-01T08:40:00Z"

TimeSlot: "2009-11-01T08:40:00Z"

TimeSlot: "2009-11-01T08:45:00Z"

TimeSlot: "2009-11-01T08:45:00Z"

TimeSlot: "2009-11-01T08:50:00Z"

TimeSlot: "2009-11-01T08:50:00Z"

TimeSlot: "2009-11-01T08:55:00Z"

TimeSlot: "2009-11-01T08:55:00Z"**
TimeSlot: "2009-11-01T09:00:00Z"

Here are the methods being used

```
TimeZoneInfo MountainTime = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Mountain Standard Time");

public static DateTime ConvertUtcTimeToMountainTime(this DateTime date)
{
    return TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(date, MountainTime);
}

public static DateTime ConvertMountainTimeToUtcTime(this DateTime date)
{
    date = DateTime.SpecifyKind(date, DateTimeKind.Unspecified);
    return TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(date, MountainTime);
}
```

What is going wrong here?

Comment: How are you generating those lists? Also, please consider copying and pasting the text into the question rather than uploading an image.

Comment: Why are you modifying `date` in `ConvertMountainTimeToUtcTime`?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan instead of posting the lists from the client I'll post the response from the server and change it to text instead of images. Give me a few.

Comment: I think @WaiHaLee is on the right track in any case. `date` is a reference, and you're altering the reference. Try changing the second function to be `return TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(DateTime.SpecifyKind(date, DateTimeKind.Unspecified), MountainTime);`

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan no luck with that change.. still shows the second output posted above

Comment: Okay, I see what the problem is. Basically, you don't want to use `DateTime` for this. You want to use `DateTimeOffset`. I'm going to suggest we close this as a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/6214633/215552, since I can't do better than that answer :).

Comment: Thank you for linking me to that!